# How can I use the Android Paid Market from a region where it's not available yet?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, paid-apps

I live in scandinavia and the Market for paid applications is not available here yet. Is there any way I can enable it? Or a workaround?

Comment: Similar question is available at :http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144/how-to-buy-apps-from-unsupported-countries-using-un-rooted-phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to root if you get a prepaid sim card from a country where paid market is visible. Of course it's bit annoying to have to change the sim from time to time...

Answer (score 3):

You need to install an application called Market Enabler, note this only works on rooted phones . You can download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/market-enabler/downloads/detail?name=MarketEnabler_latest.html)

Answer (score 2):

Both rooting and using a prepaid SIM seem a bit extreme.  I'd suggest looking at other App Markets to see if that will help before turning to such drastic measures.  I have started a question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/alternative-android-app-markets) about different App Markets and suggested two in the question.  Hopefully, there will be some replies soon and you may have your pick.