# How do I use the US Android Market from Europe?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circumvent the regional limitation in the market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/circumvent-the-regional-limitation-in-the-market)
>   [How can I buy apps from unsupported countries?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144/how-to-buy-apps-from-unsupported-countries-using-un-rooted-phone)

I am in Europe and I have an Android phone, but I cannot buy apps on the Android market? How can I overcome this limitation? I am thinking somehow registering with a US address. Is this possible?