# Google Reader Not Available in International Market

Tags: 2.1-eclair, google-play-store, google-reader

I was excited when they announced the official Google Reader app but I can't get it on the market.

I am using my Android Device from Kenya, Africa and would want to know whether being in this region affect availability of apps on the market and if so, how to work around it.

I tried searching on the market as pub:"Google Inc." and this did not help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the Google Reader app and service are no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

you can download it from [here](http://ardroid.net/apps/reader.apk) then copy the apk file on your handset and install it from there.

but I would still recommend Newsrob as a better reader even than the official google reader application

Comment: You should move that first sentence into a comment on GAThrawn's answer and keep your answer strictly as an Answer not an Answer + a comment on another persons answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [announcement on the Google Reader blog](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-google-reader-app-is-here.html) it should be avaiable for phones running donut (Android 1.6) and above, so you're covered for that.

The blog doesn't mention any geographical restrictions and I'm in Europe (UK) and I've got it, so it's definitely available outside the US.

If you've got a barcode reader, then you can just point your phone at the QR barcode [on the blog](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-google-reader-app-is-here.html) and it should take you straight to the Market page for the app (if it is in your Market).

According to [Reader's Androlib page](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-google-android-apps-reader-qCxti.aspx), it's currently available in the US, French, Spanish, Italian, German, Dutch, Japanese, Swiss and Russion markets.

There are ways to change the settings on your device so that it looks at the US (or another region's) Market, see this previous question for more [How do I use the US Android Market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-do-i-use-the-us-android-market).

Comment: if he searched for it on the market and came with no result, the QR scanning thing won't do the job at all.

Comment: It removes all doubt of spelling mistakes and similar, but that is why that's only one option I gave. See also where I mention that you can make your phone use the US Market, if that's done then the barcode scanning should work with no problem.