# android access in some countries

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use the US Android Market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-do-i-use-the-us-android-market)

Hello 
I would like to ask if there is any way to get android market in syria cuz it's not allowed 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rooted phone, you can try using [Market Enabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler) to spoof the Market into thinking you're accessing it from a country where the Android Market is available.

Comment: Thanx ...but i dont wanna root my phone any other way ?

Comment: You can use a SIM card purchased in a country where Market access is available.