# Can I use Android Emulator to get the Free apps from Amazon's app store?

Tags: android-emulator, amazon-appstore

It is said that we can test drive using Android apps even using an Web based android emulator for Amazon, but I don't see it on Amazon's Angry Birds webpage?

Can we download the Android SDK and use the emulator to use any free apps offered on the Amazon app store?

Comment: The test drive feature you mentioned is only available on certain apps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can certainly install the Amazon App Store app on the emulator.  First go to the settings and allow installation of apps from unknown sources, then open the browser and download [this app](https://amznadsi.hs.llnwd.net/e1/AmazonApps-release.apk).  This will download the app store .apk, which you can then install.

However, if you are planning to download and run Angry Birds (or other games), on the emulator, you will probably find it is too slow unless you have a very fast PC.  It might work OK for less demanding apps.

Also, beware that at the moment Amazon only permits US users to download apps (see [How can I get apps from the Amazon app store from an unsupported region?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7254/how-can-i-get-apps-from-the-amazon-app-store-from-an-unsupported-region)).

Comment: Yes, the emulator runs rather slow on even the best dev machines. And running the Honeycomb emulator is extremely slow

Comment: @Bryan There seems to be a trend of the emulator getting slower with each version (presumably it has more work to do as the platform becomes more complex).  The 1.5 emulator is quite speedy, 1.6 is noticeably slower, 2.2 is slower still and 2.3 crawls on my less-than-recent machine.  Haven't tried Honeycomb yet.

Comment: I imagine the user wants to take advantage of Amazon's free paid app every day. He or she likely didn't have an Android device at the time, and Amazon requires a registed linked device to take advantage of the free app of the day.