# Restrictions of a Kindle Fire in Canada?

Tags: localization, amazon-kindle-fire

I wanted to order a Kindle Fire in Canada but I saw that it wasn't available. Now I really wanted one and I could always just cross the border and get one. What I want to know is how restricted will it be in Canada. I hear it's probably only the Amazon content distribution system that won't work, meaning I still get a full-featured Android tablet with the Android market. I should be able to get any apps and any books from the Android market that I can normally with my phone in Canada.

Is that how it's looking?

Comment: I've got a friend bringing me mine next month, I'll make sure to answer this if no one else has by then :P.  It's possible Amazon will use (some of) the same restrictions as the Appstore, in which case [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7254/how-can-i-get-apps-from-the-amazon-app-store-from-an-unsupported-region) may be useful.

Comment: Just to be clear: the Market is *not* included on the Kindle Fire. I believe it's possible to get it if you root, but I don't know if it's possible without rooting.

Comment: @eldarerathis Oh snap, that changes everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just got a Kindle Fire as a gift.

So far I've been more than disappointed.

- No apps
- No Amazon Prime membership.
- No Cloud.
- No MP3's
- No storage.

Yes Facebook works.
Yes I can check my email.
Yes I can browse the web.

Bottom line is, if you're in Canada, spend a few more bucks and get a tablet that you CAN use...

Comment: I got a Kindle Fire and [returned it](http://magnificentnose.com/2012/02/06/thoughts-on-my-android-e-reader/) to get a proper Android tablet. Unless all you're doing is reading Kindle books, a proper Android tablet is so much nicer.

Answer (score 5):

I have a kindle Fire I received as a gift and live in Canada. The Amazon App Store is visible but you cannot download anything. It says "this service is unavailable in your region" The web browser works fine, as does downloading books from Amazon .ca
You can see the content for sale or borrowing in Amazon Prime, but get the same message.