# Amazon Android App Store International

Tags: amazon-appstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get apps from the Amazon app store from an unsupported region?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7254/how-can-i-get-apps-from-the-amazon-app-store-from-an-unsupported-region)

I followed a tutorial that would allow me to access the amazon android app store.  When I filled everything out, (account, address, one-click, etc.) it still won't allow me to download, saying that it isn't in my region.

I used this [tutorial](http://abtevrythng.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-use-amazon-app-store-outside-us.html).  What's the problem?

Comment: its not a duplicate because I'm saying that there is a problem and how to fix it, not how to get apps from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in your US proxy solution which can be detected. Use SSH Tunnelling (needs root access) or VPN.

Comment: can you recommend something that works?

Comment: @BlueFire Is it not working? Have you tried SSH Tunnelling or VPN on Android device?

Comment: I access it every day from Canada without needing a proxy...

Comment: @MatthewRead Regardless of your benefits, you should report it to them.. :)