# How does Google Play determine the region on a tablet without SIM card

Tags: google-play-store, tablet

I know Google Play uses SIM card to determine the region on cell phones. And I know Market Unlocker and Market Enabler.

How does Google Play determine your region on a tablet without SIM card?

And how to change it? I have access to IP address where Google Play is available. And I own a credit card whose billing address is in a country where Google Play paid apps are available.

Comment: The region is set in the installed firmware, so you can't change it unless your device is rooted. However, [other app stores like Amazon](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7254/7574) apparently can be fooled

Comment: @THelper Therefore, if I purchase a Nexus 7 from Google US and bring it to somewhere Google Play paid apps are not available, Google Play will behave as if I'm in US? This would be great, exactly what I want it be.

Answer (score 2):

Google uses your IP Address and visible WiFi networks, as well as the information from the Google Account you used to determine your region.

Comment: Why was this down voted? I am using my USA Nexus 7 with a Singapore Google account/credit card while in Japan and a lot of the text is in Japanese (featured sales and some games e.g. Sonic 4). So it does seem to be by IP.

Comment: @row1 Possibly due to the fact that this doesn't cite references and seems to be quite low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Your region is determined by your IP address and your account. What you see in the store is determined by your IP's location, but what you can actually purchase is determined by your Google account.

I bought a Nexus 7 from the USA and primarily use it in Singapore with a Singapore Google account and credit card. All of the prices are in SGD and I don't have access to things like books or movies.

I am currently in Japan and a lot of the Play store text and app titles are in Japanese, the prices are in Yen and I can see movies and books. I have bought some apps, but I cannot download region restricted items e.g. books and some games (even free ones).