# If I insert a Japanese SIM into my Nexus 4, can I have unlimited access to the Japanese Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-4, sim-card

I read this thread ([How does Google Play determine the region on a tablet without SIM card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32623/how-does-google-play-determine-the-region-on-a-tablet-without-sim-card)) and it seems like the region is determined by IP, but if I insert a SIM purchased in Japan into my Nexus 4, will I be able to purchase Japanese apps, games, books, etc even if I don't have a Japanese credit card, or will I need that as well?

Answer (score 1):

No, having a SIM card from a particular country does not get you that country's Play Store. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/44733/12442) on a related question for instructions from Google Play support about moving to a different country.