# How to change my device location on the Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I'm trying to download an App on the Play Store, specifically the Vue Cinema app, but this app is only (presumably) available in the UK.

I have just relocated to the UK, so how do I set my location to be the UK?

I have updated my google+ settings to say that I am currently in the UK.

Also, my google account is a Google Apps account but I don't there is any location associated with Google Apps.

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12538/how-can-i-circumvent-regional-restrictions-in-the-android-market and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144/how-can-i-buy-apps-from-unsupported-countries

Comment: Do you have a UK SIM card inserted?

Comment: @Flow yes I have, using a Giff Gaff sim card

Comment: @Flow the questions you have linked to are related, but I do want to change the location of my device as I am not temporarily visiting

Answer (score 43, accepted):

(May 2013) **I've contacted Google and this is their response:**

> Thanks for contacting us about country support for Google Play.
>
> We use the billing address of your default payment instrument in
>   Google Wallet to help determine your home country for accessing the
>   Play Store. Our collection of content can vary by country, so your
>   view of the Play Store may differ from what others are seeing when you
>   travel outside of the country listed on your default payment method's
>   billing address.
>
> Please note that you must have a valid payment method with a billing
>   address located inside a country in order to access that country's
>   Play Store.
>
> If you're having issues viewing your intended country's Play Store and
>   would like to change your default payment method or update an existing
>   billing address in Google Wallet, please use the following steps:
>
> 1) Sign into your Google Wallet account to manage your payment methods
>   https://wallet.google.com/manage/paymentMethods
>
> 2) Add a new card or change your default payment instrument to one
>   with a billing address located inside your desired country
>
> 3) Open the Play Store and navigate to any item available for download
>
> 4) Click to begin a download until you reach the "Accept and buy"
>   screen (no need to complete the purchase)
>
> 5) Close the Play Store and clear data for the Google Play Store
>   application (Settings > Apps > Google Play Store > Clear Data) or
>   clear your browser cache
>
> 6) Re-open the Play Store. You should now see the Play Store that
>   matches your default payment instrument's billing country.
>
> If you haven't yet added a payment method to your account for the
>   first time, please add a card directly from the Play Store with a
>   billing address that matches your intended country location. Then,
>   follow steps 3 through 6 to show your intended country's Play Store.
>
> If you believe that you're experiencing a different location-related
>   issue, please first verify if the country of your primary payment
>   method matches your intended country. If the countries match, please
>   provide any screenshots and additional details that might help me
>   resolve your issue.
>
> We appreciate your feedback as we continue bringing more content to
>   Google Play. Thank you for reaching out!

(July 2015) **Update**

Due to the popularity of this answer, I've decided to add bits to this answer which others have pointed out to improve and update this answer.

- The Accept and buy screen is only available on desktop (not mobile) - thanks @fwuensche
- Google Wallet has changed since the original answer was posted, also try to change your address on these links - thanks @corbacho
- [Settings](https://wallet.google.com/manage/w/0/#settings:)
- [Address Book](https://wallet.google.com/manage/#addressBook:)
- Clear all cache and data from the Play Store app
- If you're in a "family account", leave it
- Try [these steps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44677/how-to-change-my-device-location-on-the-play-store/59552#59552) of removing and adding back your account - thanks @Dushy
- Google customer support suggests it may take between 30 minutes to 24 hours for the address on the account to refresh.

Comment: In step 4, you must access the "Accept and buy" screen from https://play.google.com/ from your desktop. It won't work from the Google Play Store app for Android. It just my problem! Thanks =)

Comment: If u change ur country location, do you lose apps specific for previous countries?

Comment: I tried this and all the other answers on this page, but none of them were working on their own (I bought 2 apps with the new default payment method and even removed the google account from my device). In the meanwhile I was also trying to update my mobile phone number (for security/recovery purposes), but after receiving and confirming the code for the mobile number change it always failed on me. Turned out that this fiasco on Google servers' side was probably related with my account being stuck in the wrong country: by deleting all my old phone numbers and adding again the new one (from the

Comment: ..new country) then I've been able to obtain my play store switched to the proper country (after force closing it and clearing its data)

Comment: Worked for me: changing my address in [https://wallet.google.com/manage/w/0/#settings:](https://wallet.google.com/manage/w/0/#settings:) then clearing my browser's cache/cookies.

Comment: I also contacted Google Play support. Steps that worked for me:
Sign into Google Wallet at https://wallet.google.com/ and click the Settings icon in the top-right corner. Update your "Home address" (different from the "Address book" which holds shipping addresses).
Open the Google Play site and navigate to any paid item. Click to begin a download until you reach the 'Accept and buy' screen (no need to complete).
Close Google Play and clear your browser cache.
Wait 30 minutes.
Re-open the Google Play. It should work!

Comment: Thanks, @corbacho. Changing home address in Google Wallet worked for me! Apparently changing the address for the credit card is not the only requirement.

Comment: I got the option to 'buy' not "Accept and buy". it still works though.

Comment: And it's not needed to wait 30 minutes. Actually I saw <YOUR DESIRED UNIT>X.X in the top right corner - so it was changed during "checking/loading card".

After that - no need to remove g.account in phone. (I tried multiple times before) so thanks @corbacho !

Answer (score 5):

Tried [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/44733/41714) answer, but it didn't solve the problem. So I called Google Play support - they did have me clear data from the Play Store app, but also told me to remove my Google account from the Accounts section in settings and add it back. Then they got me to clear the data again from 'Download Manager' and 'Google Play Store' in the apps section and everything worked perfectly after that.

Answer (score 5):

Moved from the UK to Australia and required the banking apps. I had the same problem and tried various things.

What worked for me on a Samsung Galaxy S3:

- Log into Gmail on your PC and change the billing address to the new address (in my case Australian address).
- On the phone, go to *Settings*, scroll down to *Accounts* and select *Google*. Select the account which the phone has been synced with and select *Remove account* at the bottom.
- Once account has been removed go back to *Settings* main screen, select *Apps*, select *Google Play Store*, tap *Force stop*, confirm, then tap *Clear data* and tap *Clear Cache*.
- Go back to *Settings* and select *Accounts*. Add account by selecting *Google*.
- Once Google account has been added and setup on the phone go back to the main screen and open up playstore.
- Play Store is now displaying all paid apps in $$$ NOT in £££ and I am able to download the app successfully.

Comment: Things have changed since this was last discussed and there is a more definitive process by Google [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675).  However, to make this work for sure, after creating a new payment profile for your new country, close your old payment profile as per [here](https://support.google.com/payments/answer/6220311), then follow Dushy's instructions above (the _CLEAR DATA_ button is now under 'Storage' and also clears cache).  Hope this helps anyone still struggling with this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, what turned out to work in the end was to make an actual purchase.

In google wallet, I had updated all my information, as well as added a new card with my new address attached to it and set it as default. This in itself however didn't seem to be enough.

Later though, I read an article recommending us to actually purchase an app through Google Play using the new card - you'll need to wait for 15 minutes to complete the payment since that's the time you're allowed to require a complete refund.

Finally, I closed the Play Store and completely reset the Google Play Store application (i.e. go to Settings > Apps > Google Play Store, and click on Force Close, then Clear Data, and Clear Cache).

After that I could access things in Play that were only available to my new credit card's country, which previously I could not see due to regional restrictions.

Hope it helps you guys!

Comment: This is interesting, as you might need to purchase an app that is unavailable due to your region not being applied correctly.  at least you got it to work.  For me, it just took time

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems switching to the US store from outside the US, even clearing caches etc. I downloaded Hotspot Shield and enabled it, removed the SIM card from the phone, removed the app data for the Play Store and Download Manager and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

[Google Play support says:](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en)

> - You can only change your Play country once per year.
> - When you change your country, you won’t be able to use your Google Play balance that you have in your old country in your new country.

Once per year!!?! I'm a digital nomad. I move countries frequently.

All the above solutions working with Google Play are too cumbersome.

So, avoid Google Play and use another market app. I suggest either:

- [APKPure](https://apkpure.com/apkpure/com.apkpure.aegon)
- [Aptiode](https://aptoide.en.aptoide.com)

Both allow auto-updating apps.

Answer (score -1):

It should work if you change it from your Google account, which for whatever reason is not the same as a G+ account.

If you have gmail, I found the setting under **settings > Accounts and Import > Other Google Account settings**

right now the page looks a little small but hopefully that's just my browser playing tricks on me again

Comment: I went to GMail -> Settings -> Accounts... but there is no Accounts and Import and no Other Google Account settings

Comment: Incorrect advice.