# 12 months needed to change Google Play country because must first create profile first?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

According to [Google Play Help - How to change your Google Play country](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675), the following means
12 months are needed to change one's Google Play country, because one must first create a payments profile, and then wait 12 months first. Correct?:

> #### How to change your Google Play country
>
> If you move to a new country you may want to change your Google Play country. Your Google Play country determines what content you see in the store. The apps, games, and other content in the Store can vary by country.
>
> - You must wait 12 months after initially creating a payments profile before you can change your Play country. You can only change your Play country once per year. If you change your country, you won’t be able to change it back for one year.

Comment: Possible dupe of [How to change my device location on the Play Store](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44677/44325), particularly [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216831/44325). It means that you can only change the country once per year.

Comment: The secret apparently is one needs one Payment Profile and not two, for best results.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the resolution to this problem will probably involve deleting other profiles that one had previously created. Here's a slice of my discussion with the chat person of Google:

> 8:18:22 AM Katherine: As an alternative, we will once close the old profile, so that the new profile is updated on the Play Store.
>
> 8:18:40 AM Katherine: Not to worry, you'll have 29 days to re-open a closed profile. In case, if you will need the old profile, you can contact us again to re-open the profile.
>
> 8:19:20 AM 積丹尼 Dan Jacobson: But next year when I go back to Taiwan I will still need the old one ...
>
> 8:20:11 AM Katherine: Once you get back to Taiwan, you can get back the old profile re- activated."

(So I did what she told me and in the end it worked.)

Comment: In fact, once one changes to the First World Country, one might find the advantages exceed changing back to the Third World Country, even upon returning there.

Comment: This method worked for me. I changed country and created a new payments profile, then tried to join a Google Family with others from the new country. I was unable to as it didn't recognise the new payments profile. Deleting the old one, joining the family, and then reinstating the old one (in case I travel back) worked.