# How to purchase an app on Google Play without a credit card?

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread

I live in India and I don't have a credit card. I have tried using debit cards, internet banking and a virtual credit card from my bank (State Bank of India), but none of them work.

How can I purchase an app (PowerAmp) without a credit card?

Google Wallet is not acceptable because my phone runs Gingerbread and it isn't compatible.

Comment: Have you considered using the Amazon App Store ?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work for amazon either

Answer (score 5):

I am from India.  I think Google play gift card is not available in India till now.  I will tell you a method through which you can purchase android apps from Play Store in India without credit card.

The only legal way to buy paid apps from Play Store other than credit card is by creating Virtual Credit Card. Virtual Credit Card is an artificial credit card which acts similarly like any ordinary credit card and you can use it for on line shopping. But in virtual credit card you have to transfer the amount first just like debit cards.

There are two trusted ways of creating Virtual Credit Card -

- Create Virtual Credit Card from bank - Many banks are having a service of creating a virtual credit card for online shopping. STATE BANK OF INDIA and HDFC BANK are two banks which I have used for creating Virtual Credit Card especially HDFC BANK's NetSafe service is awesome and just perfect for any online shopper. Amount charged for creating virtual credit card is very minimum.
- Create Virtual Credit Card from [Entropay](https://www.entropay.com/) - If your bank doesn't give the service of creating virtual credit cards then you can use ENTROPAY for purchasing apps from the Play Store. Entropay is an online service which I strongly recommend for creating virtual credit cards, as it is completely safe and secure. All your information is protected by encryption. Creating virtual credit card through is very easy you just need to fill up your details and your virtual credit card is ready in minutes, now transfer your fund to virtual credit card and start shopping. EntroPay is used worldwide and processes thousands of transactions daily. For using EntroPay you need to pay certain charges.

Earlier Google only sells android apps through its Play Store in India but now Google has start selling books and movies also, so this Virtual Credit Card method work perfectly with them also means you can buy android apps, eBooks and movies without credit card using Virtual Credit Cards.

I hope this post is helpful for you.

Comment: i have already created state bank virtual credit card worth rs 100.but google play says : invalid credit card

Comment: you should just go get another card from banks like ICICI. That's your only option as of today.

Comment: Entropay for me with pnb debit card, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can mail-order a Play Store gift card - https://play.google.com/intl/en-US_us/about/giftcards/#lightbox

Comment: The google play cards are really usefull to keep a connection to the bank or credit card off the account. (limited ammount to drain) .   I use them myself, but it should be noted that they still land in a "google wallet" when extracted into the system of thiers.  I did not know this was something that cannot be done on some systems, because it seemed like it was based on the store app itself.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your intention of buying applications in spite of the difficulty you face.

If your question is about only buying Poweramp, you can buy it from its [website](https://secure.payproglobal.com/orderpage.aspx?products=47845) directly.

The website permits following payment options (and Paypal):
[image]
You can try your State Bank of India's debit card (old card is a Maestro and the new one is Visa) or even the virtual card.

Comment: Did you notice the amount difference ?? In play store its only 59 . If I pay through the given site, I have to pay 190 Rs extra. Anyway thank for your answer, I purchased app using my frnd CITI bank credit card.

Comment: That's because Poweramp is being sold at a special price in India, Russia and Brasil (see [here](http://powerampapp.com/buy-poweramp/)).

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Cards can be bought at many stores (depending on your country).

There are also Websites providing instant Gift Card-codes.

I have personally used and can recommend [this site](http://www.playgutschein.de/play-gift-card.php) for German speaking countries.

For everyone that is interested in keeping banking information away from Google (as far as that is possible today) that is the only viable option.

The codes are redeemed within the Play Store --> Options --> Redeem Gift Code

The money is then added to your account to use on any app, movie, music or In-App-Purchase.