# Alternatives to the Android Market

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps, authorization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the alternative Android app markets?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/what-are-the-alternative-android-app-markets)

I've had issues downloading paid applications from the Android Market and it seems I'm [not the only one](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=768ff3029eb670cf&hl=en). I've set up my account correctly (I've been billed) but the download sticks on "Authorizing credit card...". I've tried cancelling and rebooting, but without success. I see that some in the linked thread got it working after leaving it on overnight, I left mine on for more than a day and still no joy.

For the particular app I was after I found it at [slideme.org](http://slideme.org), but their selection is very limited. I'm looking for other sites that will allow me to purchase paid apps that have a comprehensive selection.

Comment: Your best bet is to remedy your problem. Alternatives will leave you disappointed. Try clearing your Market cache (from the Settings > Applications > All Applications menu) to see if that helps.

Comment: You can try removing your credit card on Google Checkout and adding it again.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but see my comments on some of the answers, I've tried several variants without success.

Answer (score 6):

I am using [AppBrain.com](http://appbrain.com) and I am happy with it.

Comment: AppBrain just redirects to Android Market for downloads & purchases.. It works just like a catalogue, not a full-featured Market.

Answer (score 4):

The only competing powerful market alternative available is [Amazon AppStore](http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b?ie=UTF8&node=2350149011). It provides a paid app for free daily. The only thumbs down thing about it is that its available for only few countries. But, this limitation can be by-passed easily (Google it).

Another alternatives worth looking:

1. [SlideME](http://slideme.org/)
2. [AndroidPIT AppCenter](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/app-center)
3. [GetJar](http://www.getjar.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Answering the underlying problem rather than the symptom, I had the same problem with the market.  It turned out to be a problem with Google Talk.

Try starting the Google Talk application, sign in, sign out then exit the application.  Go to the market, cancel any pending downloads and start the download again.

Comment: Just a quick note on Google Talk. According to Gina Trapani on This Week In Google a couple of weeks ago, the Google Talk Service is not as most would assume to be the messaging service but in fact the service that pings back to Google with your phone presence on the network. It is also what receives the push from Google with any app to install as these are done via push rather than pull.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried repeatedly variations of "turning it off and on again". This includes removing and re-adding my details, signing in and out, actually rebooting. I understand t he problem is with Google's authorisation server and it is luck of the draw if your purchase is authorised, see the first link in my post.