# Can I install apps on phone without using the Android Market?

Tags: applications, installation, side-loading

I have this Huawei Device that does not come with the Android Market installed.

Is there any work-around for this? As in how can I install Android Apps without the Android Market?

Is there a way to install Appbrain w/o having to go through the Android Market?

Comment: "Huawei Device" - is this a phone, a tablet, or what? Do you have a model number to throw at us?

Answer (score 13):

If your device allows it (AT&T only recently started producing phones that do) there is a setting which allows you to install non-Market apps. Then you can install APKs from anywhere, assuming you can get them on your device.

On my Droid, at least, the setting is at `Settings | Applications | Unknown sources`.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the .apk files from developers' sites or other forums like androidfreeware.org and alternative markets like slideme.org.

Al Everett's answer above is part of the solution.

After changing the settings to enable you to install 3rd party apps, you can either upload / add the APKs of apps that you want on to your SD card and then using a File Manager, install them by tapping them and letting the Package Installer run the setup.

**OR**

You can navigate the sites listed above and download the APK using the default browser - I recommend you install a file manager like [Astro](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/app/astro-file-manager) so you can navigate to your SD card and install apps.

Answer (score 7):

Use slideME.
Download the apk from [here](http://slideme.org/sam2.apk) tp your phone, then install the application from your phone and you can use that to download and buy apps.
See [this question: Alternative Android App Markets](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/alternative-android-app-markets) for a list of Market alternative

Edit: Don't forget to enable non-market installation in Settings > Applications > Unknown sources

Answer (score 1):

Look from [List of Open Source Android Applications on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Open_Source_Android_Applications).

- [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org/repository/)
- [SlideME](http://slideme.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

id device is 2.2 or below

just enable check Settings -> Applications -> Unknown sources.

on 3.0 +
enable check Settings -> Security -> Unknown sources

Answer (score 0):

You can download apps from Play Store using Yalp Store app which doesn't require google account or services installed. It's free and open source.

Download it from:

1. [GitHub](https://github.com/yeriomin/YalpStore/releases)
2. [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/)

Comment: A correction is required. It says [here](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/): "*By default Yalp Store connects to Google services using a **built-in account**, so you do not have to own a Google account to use it.*" So the app does require a Google account, but not necessarily yours.

Answer (score 0):

1. First turn on an option to allow installing apps out of Google PlayStore : `Settings > Applications > Unknown sources > accept the warning message`.
2. Simple download the APK from [apkmirror.com](https://www.apkmirror.com) and install it.