# How can I add the market to my device?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, google-play-store, pandigital-novel

I have a [white Pandigital Novel](http://www.pandigital.net/pandigitalnovel) that I [hacked to run Android 2.1.](http://www.slatedroid.com/index.php?topic=5098.0)  The firmware I have did not come with the market.  Is there a way I can put the market on it?  Is there a "market.apk" somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Android Market is not a freeware, unlike the rest of Android OS, so I'm not sure if there is a legal way to install it on your custom OS. I suggest you take a look at these threads:

- [Alternative Android App Markets](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/alternative-android-app-markets)
- [Install Apps on phone with no Android Market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3476/install-apps-on-phone-with-no-android-market)

Answer (score 1):

[Androidtablets.net has a topic](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/pandigital-novel/1772-mod-rooted-pdn-rom-7-24-8-6-8-20-versions-market-volume-hack-built.html) about a ROM for your device that has the Market on it.  I'm not sure if you can just take the market.apk from that one or if you'd need to flash the entire ROM, but it looks like you can get the market on that device.

Comment: Yes, I know my device *can* support the market.  I would like to know *how* I can add the market to it and I'm hoping to avoid another full flash.

Comment: I downloaded the linked firmware but could not find a specific market file.  Through Googling I did find a file a believe to be the market named "Vending.apk".  I first tried installing that on an emulator to see if that was the market but I received an error:`PARSE ERROR: UPEXPECTED EXCEPTION OCCURRED!`.  I put it on my SD card then ran "Apps Installer" but it refused to install it.  It just said: `Application not installed`

Comment: You probably need to put it in /system/app (you need root to do so) and the device *should* register it, reboot possibly required.