# How can I root my Pandigital Novel 7" Tablet?

Tags: rooting, pandigital-novel

I have a Pandigital 7" that is updated as far as the firmware updates go. However, I do not have access the Android Market and I do not have root access.

I am trying to install a SQL reader that I found on SlideMe.org and it says to update my ROM, but I have the most up-to-date firmware from the [Pandigital Website](http://www.pandigital.net/ANDROID).

I also found a link for a firmware update Android Open Source Kit here: http://www.pandigital.net/?PageID=335

Does anybody know if this open source kit will give me root access?

Comment: From what I understand there hasn't been a way found to root the Novel, but you can install apps over USB via `adb` if you do some other hacks.  I doubt the update you link to will give you root, but a newer version of Android is probably better than nothing.  Related: [Market on Novel](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/how-can-i-add-the-market-to-my-device)

Answer (score 3):

[Slatedroid](http://www.slatedroid.com/) and its [Wiki](http://www.slatedroid.com/wiki/index.php/Introduction_to_the_Pandigital_Novel) is IMO the best resource for the Pandigital Novel. The Novel does not do any signing checks of its firmware and it's running Android 2.0 so it's rather easy to root.

EDIT: I have learned that the bootloader is encrypted; my previous sentence about "not checking signatures" may be incorrect. (It may only be that the bootloader cannot be replaced.)

[Latest community-modified firmware as of this writing](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/15444-alternate-wpdn-firmware-op-based-opdn-current-version-211/)

[Flashable a-la-carte enhancements (including root)](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/14744-kewlguys-114-127-215-32-wpdn-sd-card-enhancements/)

I notice you posted over there too, so this is really for anyone else that has a PDN 7" and wants this information.

As of note, the White and Black versions are different; the White is regarded as better.