# Where can I get Android Market App for my Tablet?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add the market to my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/how-can-i-add-the-market-to-my-device)

I do not have Android Market App installed on my Tablet. When I try download Google Maps App - it redirects me to link which look like that `market://details?id=com.goodle.android.apps.maps` and my browser fails on it. I guess I have to have Android Market App installed in order to install other apps. Right? Where can I get Android Market App ?

Comment: Which tablet do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps and Android Market are not freeware apps, and are available only on Android devices certified by Google.  Aside from using other marketplaces, you can try installing 3rd-party custom ROMs such as CyanogenMod (if available for your device) that provide Google apps as an add-on.