# Using Multiple Devices With the Play Store

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I've been using a Droid (original model) for a while and recently I bought an Archos 7 Home Tablet at Office Depot (I think it was on clearance, but I don't remember why it was marked down).  I registered the Archos tablet online, then tried to download some apps so I could start using it.

The selection was small, so I went to the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) and logged in with my Google ID.  When I tried to download apps, it told me they would not work on my phone -- but I was using a tablet.

This tablet is not the easiest to type on (which shouldn't be a big issue for what I have planned for it), and that's making it frustrating trying to enter data for forms or to deal with anything.  At this point, my understanding is that Archos seems to have their own app store that I was using when I registered my tablet.

But now I want to use the Play Store I linked to above, but when I go there, it always tries to download to my phone, not to my tablet.

How do I tell the Play Store that I have multiple devices and tell it to download apps for the device I'm using?  I tried setting up another Google account, but it wants my email address and when I give it, then Google says it's used by another account.

How can I use the Play Store with both devices?

Comment: Do you have "Market" in your list of applications in your tablet? Also the model of your table would be helpful.

Comment: Please don't call Android Market "App Store", sounds too Apple-ish... Also, it can be confused with the third-party app stores (such as Amazon's).

Comment: Related: [How can I add the market to my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/how-can-i-add-the-market-to-my-device).

Comment: Until I read @Gautham C.'s answer below, I assumed there were certain standards to any Android device, but now I realize that's wrong.  This device has Android 1.5, is using the smart phone version, and cannot access the Android Market.  I found this out by reading reviews, so I guess even though it was cheap, it wasn't a good buy.  But at least I can still probably use it with the carputer I'm working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to check your tablet version. My suspicion is that it isn't running Honeycomb (Android 3.0+ or the tablet version of Android) but actually a heavily modded phone version of Android (i.e Android 2.1-2.3).

Go to settings -> about phone (or something similar. each manufacturer changes how you access this)

If it is indeed running the version of Android meant for phones, then the market might be complaining to your tablet because you might be trying to download apps meant for honeycomb.

The online market automatically updates to include additional devices when you activate them (i.e when you initially do the android setup and sign in to your google account). Make sure you select the drop down and check if there is another option. Also make sure you activated both devices under the same account.

-I know I should have made this a comment but its too long of an answer for one. :P

Comment: I don't see a version of Android, I see a Kernel Version number that looks more like a Linux kernel version.  It's 2.6.25 and there's a build number.  Added: I finally Googled for reviews.  It's running Android 1.5 and one review mentions from the start that it can't use the Android market.

Comment: I believe you need Android 2.2+ in order to use the latest version of the Android Market app which ties into the Android Market site. Here's a full list of supported devices from Google: http://support.google.com/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1727131&topic=1100168&ctx=topic

Comment: Ouch, Android 1.5.  That version is nearly obsolete now. I would check XDA Forums and see if there are any custom roms you can flash to it that would bump it up to a newer version of Android.