# Download free-software apps from official Android Market without logging in

Tags: applications, google-play-store, downloading

The Android Market has some apps which are free software, which entails that anyone can redistribute them; and that are also zero cost. (An example is [Theremin](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.ugosan.theremin), but I'm not interested only in that one specific app.)

So for those apps, there's no good reason for me to register with the Market in order to get those apps and install them. I have no interest in registering with the Market.

It would be good if such free-software and zero-cost apps were available at more places, like the [FDroid Repository](http://f-droid.org/repository/), which doesn't require anyone's credentials in order to get the apps.

(Please note: this question is **not a request for other app stores**, that's not the issue.)

But the Android Market doesn't have an obvious way to download apps without logging in. How can I do so?

Comment: As you stated, FDroid is the best place for FLOSS applications. However it requires "unknown sources" checked, which means certain AT&T users are out of luck.

Comment: Related: [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330/1465)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install apps on phone without using the Android Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3476/can-i-install-apps-on-phone-without-using-the-android-market)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot download apps from the Market without an account associated with your device.

The only way to get apps without the Market (or an alternative market) is to get it directly from the developer and "side-load" it.

Answer (score 1):

Google has no way of distinguishing between software that is free but licensed and freeware that has no restrictions (though they could enforce some sort of selection for licence type on upload if they wanted, of course). There is no way (without hacking, presumably) to download apps from the Market without logging in.  There's nothing to stop an app maker from providing an alternate download, though.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cannot.  Any app that you download through Google's Android Market requires a Google account.

There are some alternative markets for Android out there.  Check out Amazon's Appstore and SlideMe.org for example.  You may find some of the apps you're interested in there.

Comment: and m.getjar.com