# Install application in SD card or external USB drive without root?

Tags: usb, external-sd, installation

Is it possible any of the following in a **non-rooted** Android device?

1. Install an application "manually" (without using Android Market/Google Play)
2. Install an application in an external SD card
3. Install an application in an external USB drive connected to the device

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here. #1 is certainly possible; it's called side-loading. The rest looks like you're asking generic information about an app you'd like to build. We're not here for programmers, but for end users. Unless you can [edit] your question to show how this is something that would be useful to an end user, I'm afraid it's likely to be closed.

Comment: Also, as Al noted: please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/48111/edit) your question and keep only one item in. Feel free to post each of your questions separate -- that's how this site works. [How do I ask a good question?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How To Ask Android Questions The Smart Way](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1181/16575) will help you on the way to successfully dealing with this site, and get the most out of it :)

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice, I removed the second part of the question to make it only app-installation specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. See: [Can I install apps on phone without using the Android Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3476/can-i-install-apps-on-phone-without-using-the-android-market)
2. You can't install directly to the SD card. In many cases you can move much of the app and its data to the SD card, but the OS and the app have to support it. Even then, you need to install normally and then move it, and you can't move 100%.
3. Not without a custom ROM, and maybe not even then.