# How to install and uninstall apk application from MAC to my mobile android?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/how-can-i-install-an-app-given-only-its-apk-file)

I need to install a apk application into connected android mobile in my mac.Is there any way to install it?

Answer (score 10):

From the command line you can run `adb install app.apk` (requires [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)).

Or, put the `*.apk` on a website and then go to the URL on your Android device and you will be prompted to install the APK.

Comment: Just to clearify this: `adb install app.apk` requires that you have the Android Software Development Kit (SDK) installed on your mac

Comment: I get -bash: adb: command not found

Comment: @EliaWeiss You need to add the path to where `adb` is located to your PATH environment variable, or run it using the full path. I did this: `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb install path/to/my.apk`.

Answer (score 3):

Put the file into Dropbox, and use the Dropbox app on the device. It's very easy, and works a treat.

Comment: Should be the answer :)