# Unable to install any application on my android phone

Tags: installation

I am an absolute newbie on the android scene, recently I purchased a cheap android phone.Unbranded,chinese make. Mainly to experiment. I am trying to install the apps but it simply won't allow me to add anything . Not even a bigger Phone book.

The menu system - settings-> Applications is simply not there. I have downloaded the .apk's from the computer ,but it simply will not allow me to place it anywhere. I am getting the reply "unsupported media". Why is this and how do I work around it?

I shall be grateful for any help.And what is a T-flash Card?

Comment: No model number or anything?

Comment: Is there a menu under system settings that says "About Phone"? If this menu is present, what does it says under software information and phone identify (if anything)?

Comment: Have you looked through the options on this other question that has various options for side-loading apps on to the device? [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/how-can-i-install-an-app-given-only-its-apk-file)

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this isn't a knockoff Android with a different OS that is skinned to look like Android, or one that's running some kind of weird custom ROM. There are a huge number of "Android" tablets and phones coming out of China lately; some are legit and some aren't. If you look at sites like dealextreme.com, you'll see some pretty wild stuff.

If it's an actual Android phone, the contacts can be synced from a Gmail account, or manually added in Contacts. Unless the phone has a SIM card and you're saving contacts directly to the SIM, you won't really run into a hard limit on phonebook entries. The small phonebook, the "unsupported media" error and the missing Applications menu makes me a little suspicious that the phone might not be what it seems.

I would be extremely interested to see some pictures of the phone if possible. Aside from general interest (I'm sort of a knockoff phone enthusiast, if there is such a thing), maybe some photos would help us figure out what type of phone it is and whether or not you'll be able to load any apps on it somehow.