# How can I install Firefox on an Android with no service or Google account?

Tags: installation, firefox-for-android

This is for a very narrow use case with a phone that is used as a mobile GUI environment only. The phone has no service and is not associated with a Google account, so it can't access Google Play. Is there another way to install Firefox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can grab the latest .apk on a PC from [Mozilla's FTP server](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/mobile/releases/latest/android/) and sideload it, as noted on [Mozilla's wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android#Download_Firefox_for_Android).

If you're unsure of how to sideload an app, you can find a variety of methods in [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/how-can-i-install-an-app-given-only-its-apk-file) (some require internet connectivity, many do not).