# Is it possible to install/update apps from Google Store via PC?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, installation, apk

A few months ago I was forced to uninstall some apps in order to update other ones. Recently I've lost the ability to receive email notifications via Gmail (searching works, however). All because of trash apps Google Play and Google Play Services, which are constantly growing. I plan to completely uninstall them, at least regaining the functionality my phone had 2 years before.

However, if I would have to do the update of some app, or I would like to install new one, is it still possible to do it via PC connection? How to download application to my PC in order to install it to my phone?

Note: I've already lost the ability to update or install new apps because of too little storage on internal memory card.

Comment: Sounds essentially like you want a combination of [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330) and [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5566)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Java application to do this, which can be [found here](http://lemmymorgan.com/how-to-extract-direct-apk-links-from-google-play-store-android-market/). It's called the *Real APK Leecher*. It works by pretending to be an Android device (you need to configure it with your Playstore account data), so it connects to the corresponding Google services like any other Android device with the Playstore app installed, let's you browse the Playstore, and download APKs. I didn't try it out myself, though; but you might wish to give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to install apps from pc for your mobile device, even if you don't have a net access.

1. First open Google Play on your pc through your GMail account connected with your device.
2. Then open APK downloader and download the APK extension for your web browser.
3. In the Google Play Store click on the app you want to install in your mobile and then click on the green apk button which will automatically appear on the html bar . You r apk file will begin to download.
4. Connect your device to the pc through usb cable and copy the downloaded .apk file in your device. For more information on how to download apk extension please refer to this website. http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/

Hope it helps. I don't know how to update via pc... but installation can be done like this.

Answer (score 0):

By time being from my knowledge It is not possible to install from play store to Android through PC.

Since play store installs APK to android device only not to PC.

You can mange it from PC by signing-in to play store from your PC.
When your phone get connected to internet play store installs directly 
your app or update to phone

From This guide you can install/uninstall app from PC to Android using following link

```
http://www.wondershare.com/mobile-phone/android-app-installer.html
```

Answer (score 0):

www.mobogenie.com provides a Windows based tool called MoboGenie that uses your computer's network traffic to install and update apps in your android phone.

You need to connect your phone with the computer, and have a high speed internet connection

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is totally possible to download apps from the Google Play Store using your PC connection .... as stated above you just need to attach your device with the PC using USB, sign into Google Play Store with your Gmail account and select the app from the Play Store and click on Install .... it will ask for permission to install and then will download and install the app on your device.

Hope this is helpful....

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking.