# How do I get an android media player without going to the google play store ? I will transfer the media player to the smartphone using bluetooth

Tags: installation, media-player

How do I get an android media player without going to the google play store ?

I will transfer the media player to the smartphone using bluetooth.

step 1: I download the android media player to my notebook.

step 2: I transfer the android media player to my smartphone.

step 3: I install the android media player on my smartphone.

Comment: Also (if you've already found a media player APK from the author's website): [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On your notebook, look for a **FREE** app (in your case, a *media player*) in Google Play.
2. Copy the link of the app in Google Play.
3. Paste the link on [APK Downloader](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/), and download the APK file to your notebook.
4. On your phone, make sure you allow external APKs to be installed. On my Samsung Galaxy S4, this is on `System settings > More > Security > Unknown sources`.
5. Using bluetooth, transfer the file from your notebook to your phone.
6. Once download is complete on your phone, look for the APK file and install it.