# How to install a file manager to Xperia L WITHOUT internet connection?

Tags: installation, offline

It's a big **shame** that this phone does not have any file manager by default.

I have the .apk installer of the file manager on my PC, but how to install it on phone **offline**? (offline = no internet connection)

Help

Comment: See this previous question for several good ideas, especially `adb install`: [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5566/11343)

Answer (score 0):

Plug the device into the computer, drop the .apk into the sd card and use the web browser to go to `file:///sdcard` and open the .apk file to install it.

Comment: I would suggest adding your answer here instead: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5566/11343