# How to install an app outside Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, apk

How can I install an apk app outside of Google Play. Like if I downloaded it from another site and I try to open it, it says unable to install and I read that you have to do something to get it to work. What do you have to do?

Comment: Have you seen our [installation tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/installation/info)? Also see: [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5566/16575)

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to Settings > Security and tick "Unknown Sources" or depending on your device/OS version "Allow Unknown Sources." You can then side load an apk file. It maybe a slightly different place depending on the manufacuturer. E.g. Samsung is Settings > More > Security.