# Execute APK in /data/local/tmp?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, apk

I built an APK using [Apache's Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). I also used Ant to install it on a Cyanogenmod device:

```
$ cd Android-PRNG
Android-PRNG$ ant debug install
...
install:
    [echo] Installing .../AndroidPrng-debug.apk onto default emulator or device...
    [exec] 1476 KB/s (17773 bytes in 0.011s)
    [exec]  pkg: /data/local/tmp/AndroidPrng-debug.apk
    [exec] Success

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

So I have the APK located at `/data/local/tmp/AndroidPrng-debug.apk`.

The problem I am having is I cannot figure out how to run it. The APK does not show up in the Apps Launcher (that's somewhat expected). Cyanogenmod's FileManager v1.0.2 does not appear to let me navigate to `/data/local` (that's not expected).

How, exactly, do I execute the APK I just pushed to the device?

---

I'm working this way because Eclipse and the Android plug-in are so broken they are basically unusable.

Comment: I believe this is off-topic.

Comment: If you need to invoke Apache Ant, this isn't the forum. Also you may want to expand upon what why are you aren't using something like Android Studio or adb.

Comment: SarpSTA and Morrison - Apache Ant has already been run. The APK is on the device. Now I'm trying to execute it. Surely a question how to run an app is on-topic on these forums???

Comment: @jww, [this site is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/286110). Anyhow, is the device rooted or do you have access to ADB? If the device is rooted, copy the APK to `/data/app`  and restart. If you have ADB or a terminal emulator in device, you can do `am start -n com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity -d "file:///data/local/tmp/AndroidPrng-debug.apk" --user 0` -- this would begin traditional sideloading of an APK.

Comment: APKs aren't executables, they're archives. If Ant doesn't do the actual package install step then you need to do that. [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/how-can-i-install-an-app-given-only-its-apk-file)