# adb fails with exit code 15

Tags: adb, shell

I run a console app (built with NDK) on an Android phone with the following command from my Windows machine:

```
adb push MyApp /data/local/tmp
adb shell "cd /data/local/tmp && chmod a+x MyApp"
adb shell "cd /data/local/tmp && ./MyApp"
```

basically it works on most the phones, but on a specific phone the first two commands succeed, but the third command fails with exit code 15 (`adb` exits with code 15).

What does code 15 mean? (The app itself does not have exit code 15).

I do not have an access to that specific phone, and need an idea on what can cause this.

Where are the docs on `adb` exit codes?

For example, if the app simply fails to start `adb` exits with code 1.

Comment: apps are executed with [am start](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131046/execute-apk-in-data-local-tmp#comment163694_131046)

Comment: @alecxs app are installed with `adb install`, but not `adb push`

Comment: I wonder if it's an output by ADB or by the Android shell. Can you try again by entering the Android shell first (`adb shell`) and then executing the rest of the commands, or alternatively using an on-device terminal app?

Comment: By "console app" do you mean a simple command line program, as you might write on any UNIX-like system, or something different? Is it in C, C++, or what? What version of Android were you compiling for? What version of Android does the phone in question have?

Comment: @JohnDallman Yes it is a console program in C++  like `int main() { return 0;}`. Android NDK r20b, Android 10.