# How to delete an app installed with Amazon Appstore?

Tags: uninstallation, amazon-appstore

I've installed an app using Amazon Appstore, but I don't see a way to uninstall it. Amazon support has failed to respond to my question after 2 days.

I prefer a method that does not involve deleting it with a file manager or some sort of root access.

Comment: Sidenote:  Has the Amazon app store even been open for 2 days?  I thought it just opened yesterday... :-\

Comment: @loneboat - This was actually the second thing I noticed about it.  The first was how much it bugged me that you can't download a free app without turning on One-Click and therefore associating a CC# with your account.  Super lame.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the homescreen hit the menu button and select `Settings`.  Then select `Applications`, and then `Manage applications`.  Find the app you want to uninstall and select it, then clear the data associated with it by tapping `Clear data` and then tap `Uninstall`.

Voila!

**Edit:** I actually just noticed this in [Amazon's official help documentation](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=help_search_T1_1-3?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200551840&qid=1308084810&sr=1-3) for their Appstore (from June 14th, 2011):

> ...
>
> **Amazon Tested**
>   To ensure the highest
>   quality apps in our catalog, we take
>   all submissions through a series of
>   tests. In this process we screen the
>   apps for known viruses and malware,
>   test the app to check that it actually
>   does what it claims to do, and test
>   whether the app affects the stability
>   of the other functions of your phone.
>   These tests include (but are not
>   limited to):
>
> - **Installation:** The application installs
>     and opens, upgrades can be installed
>     *and the application can be uninstalled
>     by following the phone's regular
>     uninstall method.*
>
> ...

(Italics added by me.)

Clearly they intentionally left out an Amazon Appstore-native method of removing apps you've downloaded and installed from them.

Comment: I knew it was something right under my nose. My mistake was expecting the feature to be in the Amazon Appstore app itself. Thanks.

Comment: @James Roth - Yeah, it really is dumb that Amazon didn't think to add that feature to their store.  Amateur hour over there.  By the way, do the site a favor and don't forget to mark answers as "correct" if they helped you solve your problem; it reflects in the site's stats since it's still in Beta (it also helps both our rep scores :-D).

Comment: Will do. StackExchange is doesn't allow users to mark the question as correct within 10 minutes of it being asked.

Comment: @James Roth - Really?  Sorry about that then, I didn't mean to sound like a prick.  I've never encountered that.

Comment: @JonnyP There's also some debate about accepting answers too quickly, see for example http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/64/answers-accepted-too-soon

Comment: @Matthew Read - Very interesting... that's definitely a legitimate concern.

Comment: I dont see the "application" options under Settings. Im working an HTC Evo and trying to delete an amazon app. Why must they make it so difficult? Its more than a little frustrating.

Comment: that's standard application uninstall, right? :D

Comment: @Pitto - Indeed.

Comment: Well this is just dandy, because the OS itself doesn't recognize the app as being installed!

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, they have instructions posted on their site under the "[Your Apps & Device](https://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/your-account/myapps)" section of [amazon.com/apps](http://amazon.com/apps), support should have been able to respond to that very quickly. Uninstall is definitely lacking in the app itself.

Note: if you uninstall the Amazon Appstore itself, some apps downloaded through it may no longer function, this was confirmed with [Angry Birds Rio](http://www.droid-life.com/2011/03/22/angry-birds-rio-unplayable-if-amazon-appstore-is-uninstalled/) by [Droid-life](http://www.droid-life.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you guys checkout the updated [Amazon's official help documentation](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=help_search_T1_1-3?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200551840&qid=1308084810&sr=1-3)?

> How can I delete an app from the My Apps list?
>
> Visit [Your Apps](http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/your-account/myapps) from a web browser. Select "Delete this app" from
>   the "Actions..." drop down menu to the right of the app you'd like to
>   delete. Confirm you'd like to delete the app and your app will be
>   removed from the My Apps list on all Android devices registered to
>   your account. If the app has been downloaded to a device, it will have
>   to be manually uninstalled.

Comment: It also says if I delete, I will have to pay for the app if I want to install it again later. This is not acceptable! I need to remove because there is some sort of malfunction with the app install.

Answer (score 1):

Update: From the android app go to My Apps > Cloud, long press and it will prompt for uninstall from the Amazon Cloud level.

No more pesky accidental re-installations.