# how to delete hotels.com app?

Tags: uninstallation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

I have an app on my phone called hotels.com. I can't seem to remove it at all.
I tried going to `Application screen > Edit` but this app doesn't have a little minues next to it so I can't remove it this way.
I also tried this method:
[How to delete an app installed with Amazon Appstore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/how-to-delete-an-app-installed-with-amazon-appstore)

but the `Clear Data` and `Uninstall` buttons are greyed out.

Comment: Did it come pre-installed on your phone?

Comment: I don't know actually. I didn't notice it if it did. I noticed it after running an update on my Market app

Comment: Hmm, OK. I ask because you usually can't remove pre-installed apps without rooting the phone.

Comment: I have a Galaxy Note. Is there a way I can find out if it was preinstalled? I wouldn't mind it being there but it keeps bugging me about updates and stuff.

Comment: It sounds like it probably came pre-installed, in which case you'd want to take a look at [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)