# How can I use Google Play without storing any Google account information on my phone?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, accounts

I am using HTC Wildfire handset, but I think following question applies to all Android-based handsets.

My Google Account has been added under

```
Settings
-> Accounts & Sync
--> Google (under Manage Accounts)
```

When I click on "Google", I get following options

```
Sync Contacts
Sync GMail
Sync Calendar
```

**In Accounts & Sync option, I have turned off (unchecked following options)**

```
Background Data
Auto sync
```

NOTE: I have turned off Background Data, and Auto Sync before adding my Google Account.

I want to get apps and games from Market, but **I don't want to sync any of my Google Account data with my phone i.e., there should not be any traces of my Google Account in my phone**.

How can I do it?

Comment: An old question, but it may nevertheless still be helpful to [link to mine](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24726/can-google-services-be-firewall-filtered-market-yes-sync-no). I'm taking the approach of using Google for the market (very handy) whilst rooting+firewalling to prevent my data going to the cloud. I've not done it yet, but will update that Q if I do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beyond what you've already done, you can't.  The Market requires you to have your Google Account added to your phone, and this naturally stores data such as your email address even if you don't sync email.

Comment: oh :(

Comment: A good way to bypass most privacy concerns you may have would be to create a second Google account, putting as little information into it as possible, and using that for your phone.

Comment: @I-M-JM: or you can bypass Android Market altogether for your software needs; there are quite a few [alternative Markets](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/alternative-android-app-markets) that are not linked with Google's Android Market at all.

Comment: I second Matthew, make a second "throwaway" gmail account.  But you'll lose most of the perks of Android (syncing email, calendar, etc.)