# Is a google account mandatory to use the market?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Is a google account mandatory to use the android market?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is mandatory to use Google Account to use Google's Android Market; however it is not mandatory to use Google's Android Market to install Android applications. There are many [third party app markets](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/what-are-the-alternative-android-app-markets) and you can sideload an .apk file you have downloaded to the device (except on some devices from brain-damaged carriers where this option is disabled). Some alternative markets do not require registration.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You need one to sign in, even for free apps.  Paid apps are paid for via Google Checkout.