# Is it possible to make 'admin' user apps available on other user accounts?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, multi-user

With 4.2 on my Nexus 7 I have a few separate user profiles.

I have a number of kids games installed on my tablet admin account ('Rob'), with that account attached to a Play account.

I'd like to make those games available on another non-admin ('Callum') account, which is not attached to a Play account.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know: Not at all.

Each user account is strictly separated from another and there is no *shared folder* or app sharing concept at the moment.

I haven't checked your specific question in detail, however each user has their strictly separated userdata partition where *everything* is stored (even their media, on Nexus devices) and cannot access any other's data residing in their userdata section, which includes user installed apps (they're in /data/app/).

Comment: Interesting - so how can a user without a Play account install apps? I realise that this isn't possible on the primary account, but for a secondary account, this seems restrictive.

Comment: I guess you can get a multiuser setup working without setting up any play account, including the primary user. Side-loading will still work, i.e. just enable unknown origin apps under security. There are many [alternative app stores](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/what-are-the-alternative-android-app-markets)

Answer (score 0):

You can log into your play store account on the other profiles.  (Make sure to set a purchase pin if it's on a kids account.)  That way they will have access to any apps you purchase.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root, I have created an app, [AppShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spectrl.appshare), that will do what you want.

Paid apps will most likely require you to add the Google account that you purchased the app with to the secondary ('Callum') account or else they will probably fail the licence check. This may vary from app to app though. 
You will have no problems with free apps though, and you should even be able to disable system apps such as Gmail etc. to prevent kids messing with anything you don't want them to touch!

Without root, I think the only way to do this is add your Play account on the secondary account and add some sort of PIN protection.

Although this means that your emails could be accessed on the second account, unless you then remove it after installing the desired app (which will be a pain everytime!).