# Can Android run .exe file?

Tags: applications, installation, windows

I have just downloaded uTorrent on my Galaxy S running Android 2.3. The `.exe` file has been downloaded and is in the download folder, but when I open the download folder on my SD card and click it, it gives only one option: "Delete file".

I'm not able to run this on my phone? What do I have to do to run it?

Comment: μTorrent exists in Play Store and works well. Download it from there.
However, I would like to learn how to run .exe files on Android without using a complicated method.

Answer (score 10):

`.exe` Files are Windows binaries (i.e. executable files/applications/programms) that can not be run natively on a Android system.

I am sure the Play Store (or the [alternatives of the Play Store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/what-are-the-alternative-android-app-markets)) will have an equivalent app to the `.exe` file you are trying to run.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run `.exe` files in Android. It is a Windows executable file .
Android apps will have `.apk` format.

Check out this [link](http://www.callingallgeeks.org/3-free-and-user-friendly-torrent-clients-for-android/). They discuss about Android Torrent apps (downloaders).

Answer (score 0):

.exe is windows executable file. Like you can't run android app on windows without android emulator. In the same way you are going to need windows emulator to run .exe on android. And as far as I know no such emulator is available yet.

Answer (score 0):

.exe file will run on windows or DOS, so you probably can't open that .exe file to your android phone. But there is a way. As some .exe files are also written for DOS and android is really reliable with DOS, So you just have to install DOS box app in your phone, type the name of your .exe file, in that way you can run .exe file.

You also can use 3 party apps to make that out like - Inno Setup Extractor

Original Source :

http://joyofandroid.com/open-exe-files-on-android/

http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/make-exe-files-work-android-phone-16932.html