# Is there a shop like Cydia on iOS for Android?

Tags: applications, alternative-markets

Most apps in the Google Play store have a free version and a paid version. On iOS there is a shop called Cydia, where you can try out most apps for free before you buy them in the App Store.

Is there such a store for rooted Androids as well?

I know of the store [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) for free software

> F-Droid is an installable catalogue of FOSS (Free and Open Source Software)

Comment: There's a list of alternative app stores in this other question [What are the alternative Android app markets?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/). My understanding was that Cydia had both free and paid apps, it's main distinction was that it hosted apps that wouldn't be allowed on the app store, or required jailbreaking, it wasn't meant to be a try before you buy service?

Comment: @GAThrawn, you're correct. Although (at least when I had my iPhone 3GS) you can use Cydia to get Installous, basically a piracy platform. This may be what he's talking about. In which case, there ARE pirate android markets, but I recommend staying very far away from them because they 1: generally don't have patched/updated versions of most apps and 2: the apps from those stores may have been modified by potential attackers. (The same is also true of Installous on iOS)

Answer (score 0):

While there are Android markets offering pirated versions, (not try before you buy which is signified usually by Demo or Lite) as the other users have mentioned, installing them is very risky. I would recommend being involved in the development community. As a developer I share keys and am invited to test apps often by frequenting XDA forums and Reddit.com/r/Android. 
Developers will discount or give away versions of their apps and being involved in the community will help you learn more and score you some software deals.

*Update:This answer does not really address the question.*

Comment: To say "Cydia is a [black market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_market)" is fairly misleading. Its business model was fairly embattled in the past, but [has gained official legal status in the US](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/07/feds-ok-iphone-jailbreaking/) since then.

Comment: I do stand corrected. It has been so long since I used iOS and I switched Cydia and Installous in my memory. <br> Hopefully I can be of some help and offer Humble Bundle as a great alternative Android App store (for games) since you can purchase their android bundles when available and install through .apks.