# Free (libre) SSHD for Android?

Tags: ssh, open-source

How can I install a **sshd** server (with **scp** support) on Android **without relying on Google Play Store** for my safety?

Rooting the device or compiling the application is not a problem, but so far I'm unable to find proper instructions. I don't need a GUI either, some kind of on/off switch would be nice tho, but that's not required.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts – and thanks for sharing your solution with us! However: it would be much preferable if you'd post the answer as *answer*, instead of editing it into your question. Would you mind separating it?

Comment: I tried, but there was a time limit to answer my own question, was about to do it later when it timed out, but you were faster. I've edited my question now instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already figured out, there's *SSHelper* hosting its own `.apk`. But you might also wish to check with [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org), and find out there are [even more SSHd's to download](https://f-droid.org/forums/tag/sshd/) without using *Google Play Store*.

**Edit:** As it turns out, I wasn't aware *F-Droid* also features forums, and the above are only forum links. To compensate: You can also find some SSH Server apps on 1mobile, e.g. [SSH Server](http://www.1mobile.com/ssh-server-619252.html). The website allows you to simply download the `.apk` from your browser, no login required. Other than with *F-Droid*, I'm not sure concerning their reputation, though.

Apart from that: In my experience, it's always worth checking the resp. dev's website, where they sometimes host their own `.apk` files for download. If not, asking them helped me as well :)

Comment: What you link to are forum posts discussing sshd's. But if you take a look at the actual [repository](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=sshd&page_id=0), there are no sshd's availiable (unless you count the one included in the fullfledged chrooted version of Debian, Lil' Debi, that is a really cool idea, but seems a little overkill for just running a ssh server).

Comment: Ouch – sorry, unfortunately you are correct: I wasn't aware of the fact F-Droid also features forums. To make up for my error: please take a look at [What are the alternative Android app markets?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/216/16575) I'm pretty sure at least [AndroidPIT](http://www.androidpit.com/) has some of those servers available. [AndroidZoom](http://www.androidzoom.com/) as well. I'll update my answer in a minute...