# Unable to download apps from Play Store using mobile data

Tags: google-play-store

I have Mi4i mobile. I am trying to download  applications from Google Play Store- when I click on `Install` it  displays  "Waiting for WIFI...".

I am on mobile data, but it is not downloading through mobile data.

How can I download through mobile data?

Comment: Possibly the app you're trying to download is very big, hence Play Store recommended to use WiFi and will wait until it's connected to WiFi.

Answer (score 3):

For MIUI 8(previous versions also).
Check your 'Security' app's -> Data usage -> Restrict data usage -> System tab. Within system check Downloads is allowed to use Mobile data.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Im using mui7, try go to tools>donwloads icon>on uper right pres " ....">setting>downloads size limit, u can change by mb or unlimited..

Answer (score -1):

This will happen if you have Play Store: Settings set to Auto-update apps over Wi-Fi.

1. Cancel the download
2. Start the download manually

Manually started downloads will go through regardless of your data connection. You can also change the previously mentioned setting.

Comment: OP wrote: "*I am* ***trying to download applications*** *from Google Play Store- when* ***I click on Install***". You don't click on Install when updating an app.

Answer (score -2):

You may need to clear all data of Google Play store. I always prefer not to download from play store due to slow connection. There are many site which allow me to download apk file. See [What are the alternative app markets?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216/12442) for more details.