# What are the official APKs sites?

Tags: applications, samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, apk

Where can I find the official APKs to download them, in order to install them later on my phone without using my Samsung phone data?

Regards.

Comment: You might wish to see our [alternative-markets tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alternative-markets/info) and its posts, especially [What are the alternative Android app markets?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216/16575) Lists "official sources" along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [APK Mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/), legit APK files, never have had an issue.