# Browse only really free software on the market

Tags: google-play-store

How can I browse Google Play so that only apps/games that have no ads and no internal purchases are seen?

Note I am not talking about dedicated third party free stores, but about the actual Google Play. (Although that's a nice extra to list some 3rd party stores, but maybe it should be asked separately).

Comment: Perhaps you may need to patch Google playstore (not sure how to do that :(, but speaking of 3rd party apps, you need to take a look at [Aurora Store](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/galaxy-playstore-alternative-t3739733) its clean UI, has filters for free/paid, ads/no ads, gsf/no gsf, if you are considering alternatives

Comment: a) switch over to [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) which has only FOSS apps and doesn't permit proprietary trackers, b) use [Exodus Privacy](https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/) to check the apps, c) use [my app listings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists) which point out tracker infected as well as tracker free apps :)

Comment: I'm hoping for this feature as well. maybe a custom search on Google could give some results.

Comment: For list of third-party stores see [What are the alternative Android app markets?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216)