# How to get latest version of Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

I'm trying to solve a problem I'm having with Google Play Store. (Specifically, a continual "Error checking for updates" and an empty "Installed" list. I tried clearing the cache.)

The version I have of Play Store is 14.2.58, and I know it's not the latest. I've read that sometimes the app doesn't update automatically. But where do you go to upgrade the app manually?

When I google for it, I see a lot of third-party sites that offer the latest download, but I don't know if they can be trusted. If Google itself offers the download, I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't trust other sites, then use [Yalp](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/).

> Yalp Store lets you download apps directly from Google Play Store as apk files. It can search for updates of installed apps and lets you search for other apps. Yalp saves downloaded apks to your default download folder. Other features include browsing categories, viewing and leaving reviews, black/whitelisting apps for updates, filtering apps by being free/paid and containing/not containing ads.
>
> To supplement the features related to Google Play, Yalp Store has ordinary package manager features: listing, running, installing and uninstalling local apps

Also, visit [What are the alternative Android app markets?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216/what-are-the-alternative-android-app-markets) to get a list of other apps/places/sites that can help you get it.

Comment: It seems like an alternative to Play Store. I want to update the Play Store itself.

Comment: Use it to update Play store, then remove it.

Comment: I installed F- droid to get Yalp Store, then ran Yalp Store. I did a search for Google Play Store but did not see it anywhere in the list.

Comment: Then I recommend using Apkmirror or Apkpure to download the latest version of Google Play Store. I have use and still use their services without problems.

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest version of Google Play Store, launch Play Store, then go to Settings, then click on **Play Store version** one or two times. It will show a dialog box and the latest version will be installed.

Comment: This ought to be the best answer, but when I try it, it tells me the Google Play Store is up to date. Which I know it's not true because there's at least a 14.3 version out there

Comment: Then you need to use an APK file of the latest version of Play Store and install it manually, as mentioned in the second answer.