# Continued access to paid-for app that has been deleted from Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I paid for an app from the Google Play Store some years ago. I have been using it successfully up to yesterday.

Today, I tried to use it and it complained I wasn't licensed and redirected me to the Play Store app. However, that just gives an error "Something went wrong", or "Try again". The Play Store app still lists the app as being installed. All my other paid-for apps appear unaffected.

After some testing, I worked out that the app seems to have been deleted from the Store. I have emailed the author and am waiting for a response.

If I don't get a response, are there options to recover the use of the app?

Comment: May be the app uses a remote server and that server was shut down? AFAIK the Google Play Store license verification that happens inside the app itself should still work. Can you name the app?

Comment: @Robert I heard back from the author. google deleted the app because some paperwork wasn't completed to their satisfaction. the author is trying to get it reinstated

Comment: Possible duplicate for the general case: [Is it possible to recover purchased apps removed from Google Play?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213993/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks, yes,  I wondered about that before I posted but I discounted it because the upvoted answer states: "If an app is removed from the Play Store, it will continue to be authenticated on your device as long as it is installed" which is not my experience here

Answer (score 0):

For this particular app, a partial temporary workaround has been to disable networking (wifi / mobile data) so that the app cannot contact the license server.

Functions that require network access don't work but existing local data can be retrieved and exported.