# How do I download an app from the market that is restricted in my location?

Tags: google-play-store, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use the Android Paid Market from a region where it's not available yet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83/how-can-i-use-the-android-paid-market-from-a-region-where-its-not-available-yet)

I want to download the Kindle for Android app, but it is not available in my region. I tried to mock my GPS location to be inside the United States, but I still cannot find the Kindle app in the Android market.

How do I download an app form the market that is restricted in my locatioon?   Also, how does the android market know where I am? Does it using the GPS location?

Comment: This is not official android market, but if you link you can download it from this link: [kindle android app](http://appzapk.com/s713/kindle/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you might be looking for is an app called, MarketEnabler, it changes somenthing like the location of the market so you can access other countries markets.

MarketEnabler: https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler

With that you could change your locale and get access to market apps in another country, If I'm correct if also includes a list with countries.

Comment: this tool works like a charm, thank you very much!